# Nginx named virtual Host Not working in Vagrant

Tags: nginx, vagrant, virtualhost, vagrantfile

I started with the default nginx configurations. Modified the default configuration in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.Here is the modification.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

The base configuration in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf is left untouched.

I am running this whole setup in a vagrant box with the following configurations.(Omitted other lines for the sake of brevity.)

```
  web.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8001
  web.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.105"
```

Now if I hit 192.168.56.105 on browser I see the html page being rendered, however when I type mysite.com I get the following error message.

**Error
The requested URL can not be retrieved**

Have added the following entry in my /etc/hosts

```
192.165.56.105 mysite.com
```

Interestingly when I try the same configuration on a nginx server installed directly on a ubuntu machine it works. I am suspecting if its a problem with my Vagrant config. Could anyone please point out as to where the error could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a typo in your `/etc/hosts` file, the IP is 192.168...

```
192.168.56.105 mysite.com
```

the line

```
web.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8001
```

is useless when working with a static IP as you'll reach the server VM directly using its IP. You dont really need to setup an additional network interface

Comment: That was an embarrassing mistake, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: better have another pair of eyes !